# Database architecture for users and permissions

Tags: database, database-design, permissions, roles

I need to design a database architecture which

1. Users can have different roles with different permissions.
2. Each user can have only one level and belong to only one group.
3. Each user belongs to one group, has all crud operations on this group.
4. All users can only view other groups even if he doesn't belong to it but some types of users can only view and edit other groups they don't belong to it.
5. Each level can contain many roles and users.
   (you can think of a level as a hierarchy, and a group as a team, role is like a job title)

What I think about and correct me if I am wrong that the relation between users and roles is many to many, the relation between roles and permissions is also many to many, but the relation between user and level is many to one.
I am not sure whether to make the relation between user and group many to one or many to many, also I am not sure if there's missing relations need to be included.
Thanks in advance!

I tried to design the DB like that but I expect a better solution.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Database model with users, roles, and rights](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1732/database-model-with-users-roles-and-rights)

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
User
    Userid, PK
    Levelid, FK, Level.Levelid      # item 2, Many-to-One
    Groupid, FK, Group.Groupid      # item 2, Many-to-One
    
Role
    Roleid, PK
    
Permission
    Permissionid, PK
    
Level
    Levelid, PK
    
Group
    Groupid, PK
    
UserAsRole                          # item 1, Many-to-Many
    Userid, FK, User.Userid
    Roleid, FK, Role.Roleid
    
RoleAsPermission                    # item 1, Many-to-Many
    Roleid, FK, Role.Roleid
    Permissionid, FK, Permission.Permissionid
    
LevelAsRole                         # item 5, Many-to-Many
    Levelid, FK, Level.Levelid
    Roleid, FK, Role.Roleid
```

---

**Item 3**

You can let the application take care of that.  There is no need to link in the database, since it is implied.

---

**Item 4**, all users can only view other groups even if he doesn't belong to it

Again let the application handle visibility of other groups.

---

**Item 4**, but some types of users can only view and edit other groups they don't belong to it.

Assign the permissions to a group, link the group allowing this to the users.  Nowhere else do you mention user types...

---

**Item 5**

You have 2 links between a user and its roles.  One through UserAsRole, and one through UserAsLevel -> LevelAsRole.  You will need to remember this when building an application using this model.

---

**Last paragraph**

*I am not sure whether to make the relation between user and services [...]*

Since you did not mention services anywhere before, I am not surprised.

---

**Final thoughts**

A database model is only as good as the requirements, and doing the work of clearly identifying the objects and relations is 90% of the work done.  What I proposed here is based on the incomplete information you provided.